# jQuery toggle slide, other content not filling extra space

Tags: jquery, css, slide

When I slide the menu (15% width - left), the content (85% width - right) is not scaling to take its place. More specifically, the various content divs/images are just staying at their places, not moving and filling the created empty space.

I have tried hiding the navigation_element, and playing with auto width, position, etc.
I managed to do it by manipulating the width of the section_element via jQuery .css (so it goes to 100% when I click the slide - and back), but it is not very elegant.

```
<nav id='navigation_element'>
    // lots of links here //
</nav>

<div id='navigation_slider'>
</div>

<section id='section_element'>
<ul id='content_list'>
    // lots of ajax generated divs/images here, like the following //
    <li>
        <div id='grid'>
            <img>
            <img>
            <img>
            <img>  
            <img>
            <img>
            (...)    
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>

// the jquery for sliding //
$('#navigation_slider').click(function()
{
    $('#navigation_element').toggle('slide',{direction:'left'},700);
});

// the relevant css //  
#navigation_element
{
    text-align:left;
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
}

#section_element
{
    float:right;
    position:inherit;
    text-align:left;
    width:85%;
}

#grid
{
    height:16.5%;
    position:relative;
    width:16.5%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: wasn't supposed to be: `$('#navigation_slider').click(function()
{
    $('#navigation_element').toggle('slide',{direction:'left'},700);
});` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misstype. I edited it now. The slide is working very well.

Comment: The slide was never the problem, but the content which is static. I kinda managed to do it, but it is not very elegant.

Comment: I tried to reproduce in fiddle but I couldn't, can you make your own fiddle with content so I can help you better?

Comment: Funny, I cant seem to get the JS working properly. Anyway the content can be construed as images of sorts. They are divs with images as background and various text on them. They are all the same size.

Comment: so same issue as me. look at the which framework/version are you using and set up on fiddle.